# What is wrong with the code fragment?shows class not found exception

Tags: java, file

I have written the class Phonerecord in the same package as the file is opened for reading and writing,but the readObject() meethod can not find the class phone record?what to do?

```
package filetest;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;



/**
 *
 * @author ishtiaque
 */
public class Filetest 
{


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         try
            {
                String s="ishtiaque",s1="lfjalj",s2="lfdjalj";

             ObjectOutputStream out=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("record.ser",true));
             Phonerecord ob1=new Phonerecord(s,s1,s2);
             //System.out.println(ob1.Name);
             out.writeObject(ob1);
             out.close();


            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.err.println("Cannot open");

            }
         try
        {
                    ObjectInputStream in=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("record.ser"));
             while(true)
             {   
            Phonerecord ob=(Phonerecord)in.readObject();
            System.out.println(ob.Name
                    +" "+ob.Phone+" "+ ob.Email);
        // TODO code application logic here
             }
        }
          catch(IOException i)
          {
              System.err.printf("%s","cannot do");
          }


}
}
```

here is the class

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package filetest;
import java.io.Serializable;
/**
 *
 * @author ishtiaque
 */
public class Phonerecord implements Serializable {
     public String Name="";
    public String Phone="";
    public String Email="";

    public Phonerecord(String Name, String Phone, String Email) {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Phone = Phone;
        this.Email = Email;
    }

}
```

Comment: You append data to your file, maybe it contains some garbage? Delete record.ser file and retry.

Comment: tried but throws IOException while reading from file
i have also changed the file .ser to .dat but no change

Comment: How would `(Phonerecord)in.readObject();` even work? Is `Phonerecord` subclassing `ObjectInputStream` ? I just don't get this part of your code.

Comment: It should be useless here but try adding a `serialVersionUID`

Comment: It throws IOException because you don't have any code to end your while(true) loop. You will reach end of file.

Answer (score 0):

Your PhoneRecord has a 3 argument constructor. When you add this, it removes the default no-argument constructor. Try adding a no-argument constructor to PhoneRecord.

Also, why the while loop? There is only one record in the .ser file right? If you have a collection, then you can add the entire collection to be serialized and read it all in one go.

Edited to answer in more detail:

If you have an no argument constructor for PhoneRecord, then something like:

```
    FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fs);
    os.writeObject(phoneRecord);
    os.close();
```

can be used to write (serialize) and something like:

```
        FileInputStream   fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        PhoneRecord r= (PhoneRecord)is.readObject();
        is.close();
```

can be used to read it.

If you have a List that you want to save in one go, you can use that instead of a PhoneRecord, both in the serializing part as well as in the deserializing part.

ie use:

```
   os.writeObject(phoneRecords);
```

where phoneRecords is a collection of PhoneRecord

and

```
    List<PhoneRecord> recs = (List<PhoneRecord>)is.readObject();
```

should do the trick.